# Easily viewing postgresql and mysql results that are too wide for the terminal

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, terminal

I regularly use postgresql and mysql in the mac terminal, and I find that results that have a large number of columns become very difficult to interpret because the entire table becomes a mess. I have seen a command in postgresql that showed each row as a table of it's own (with each column having its own row), and it was very useful for checking the output of a small number of rows with a large number of columns. Does anybody know how this is done, and is there a similar technique for mysql?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a better pager than default *more*

try to use in shell

```
export PAGER=less
export LESS="-iMSx4 -RSFX -e"
```

and then in psql:

```
\pset pager always
```

other possibility is using a \x command to switch from column view to row view.

It should to work on all SQL shells that uses a pager. We used it for Vertica too.

Comment: Thanks. \x was definitely what I was looking for. Doesn't seem to work for mysql, though.